# Is semicolon ignored in C macro?

Tags: c, macros

```
#define A;

#ifdef A
    (...)
#endif
```

I thought the predecessor would take this as false; however it would goes into this condition. Is A and A; taken as the same?

Answer (score 14):

No, they're distinct.

In

```
#define A;
```

`A` and `;` are two distinct tokens.  `A` is the macro name, and `;` is its definition.  So you could, if you really wanted to, write:

```
printf("Hello, world\n")A
```

and it would be equivalent to

```
printf("Hello, world\n");
```

(But please don't do that.)

Since the only thing you do with `A` is refer to it in an `#ifdef`, all you're doing is testing whether it's been defined or not, regardless of *how* it's defined. The semicolon is irrelevant because you don't use it.

Just as a matter of style and clarity, you should always have a space between a macro name and its definition:

```
#define A ;
```

This is particularly important if the first token of the expansion is a `(` character. If it immediately follows the macro name, you have a function-like macro definition (the macro takes arguments). If there's a space between the macro name and the `(`, the `(` is just part of what the macro expands to.

Speaking of semicolons, a common error is including unnecessary semicolons in macro definitions:

```
#define THE_ANSWER 42;

...

printf("The answer is %d\n", THE_ANSWER);
```

Since the semicolon is part of the macro definition, this expands to:

```
printf("The answer is %d\n", 42;);
```

which is a syntax error.

Comment: @KeithThompson Why does A; won't be taken as a whole macro name?

Comment: @Renjie: Because a macro name has to be an identifier.